CloudLinux boot error
Is anyone able to help me interpret what this error means? It was preventing me from booting the server. I have run fsck /dev/sda1 and loginctl terminate-session 1 which seems to have worked but I've got no idea what the actual error relates to or how to fix it.
This is on CloudLinux 9.5.


Sorry, what error?

How is the grep command in your screenshot related to your question?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
